# Sets $A$, $B$, $C$, are all subsets of a universal set $U$. If $C \subseteq (A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)$, then $C \cap (A \cap B) = \emptyset$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Sets $A, B, C$ are all subsets of a universal set $U$. Prove if $C \subseteq (A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)$, then $C \cap (A \cap B) = \emptyset$.

Use set identities where possible (label identities used).

Please help a poor fool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your expression, an element in $C$ either has to be in $A\cap B^c$ (in $A$ not in $B$) or in $B\cap A^c$ (in $B$ not in $A$), therefore it is never in both (never in $A \cap B$).

Comment: If I understood correctly: let $x \in C$ such that $x \in A \cap B^c$ or $x \in B \cap A^c$, therefor $x \notin A \cap B$